# A very controversial riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

A riddle:

> Running backwards,
> Jogging still,
> Walking up above,
> But standing low.
> I do not have wings,
> yet flying I can do.
> I have not armor,
> yet I always fight.
> What am I?

So what is the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Are you...

> time?

My rationale is pretty loose, but it seems to mostly fit:

Running backwards, jogging still

> like a countdown clock / stopwatch / Choose your metaphor about time running on

Walking up above, But standing low.

> Not sure on this one

I do not have wings, yet flying I can do.

> Time flying is a pretty standard metaphor

I have not armor, yet I always fight.

> Fighting against time is also a standard metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

Are you...

> wind?

I'm really unsure, this is a good riddle.

Running backwards, Jogging still

> wind can run/move in any direction

Walking up above, But standing low.

> Movement of the wind (higher up, it can be felt but lower down it's more difficult)

I do not have wings, Yet flying I can do

> Wind flies around everywhere

I have not armor, Yet I always fight

> Fight against solid objects, which weaker wind had little resistance to